# Load page content via AJAX and then display via JQM transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have built a minor templating system for a JQM app so that I can maintain the same index.html file with common script tags, headers and footers and simply load in the main content into the content data-role.  It's working perfectly EXCEPT I lose the transitions.

For example, when someone clicks on a link I simply use `$.load` to fetch that links URL and load it into the content div.  What I would LIKE to do is use ajax to load the contents into the soon-to-be-displayed-div and then trigger one of JQM's transitions, such as slide or whatever, to slide that new div into place.

Is this possible?  `loadPage` loads an entire page and doesn't support transitions and changePage requires that I am changing a complete page.

Here is the meat of the js that runs this.  The HTML is the standard single page template:

```js
$(document).live('pagecreate', function() {
    \\ load a page in the views folder called needing.html into the content div
    loadContent("needing");
});

function loadContent (location, nav) {
    return $('#content').load("views/"+location+".html", function(resp) { 
            $(this).trigger('create');
            $('a').unbind('click').click(function (ev) {
            var $this = $(this), location = $this.attr('href');
                loadContent(location, nav);
                return false;
        })
   });
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing `$.mobile.loadPage("pages/somepage.html", {
    pageContainer: $("#centerContent")
    })`  I'm unable to have that page that has been loaded use the built in slide animations.  I was about to dive in and try to roll my own, but it seems like something that could be handled by JQuery Mobile.